# Installing zeppelin on CentOS6 with lens get compilation error

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I git clone the zeppelin from https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin.git, and make the project by running:

> mvn clean package -Pspark-1.5 -Dhadoop.version=2.2.0 -Phadoop-2.2 -Ppyspark -DskipTests

but i always get the error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, this indicates a dependency version miss-match, in this case Apache Lense.

The best way is to try re-building Apache Zeppelin from latest master, and if the issue persists - file an issue on [official project JIRA](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN)